Highcharts negative logarithmic scale not working for the xAxis even with the logic provided by Highcharts
I know Highcharts doesn't recommend negative values when applying the logarithmic scale but they provide us with a logic to overcome this. This logics works for yAxis but not for the xAxis. Check the Fiddle below JSFiddle
`function allowNegativeValues(H) {
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
const logAdditions =
H._modules['Core/Axis/LogarithmicAxis.js'].Additions.prototype;
H.addEvent(H.Axis, 'afterInit', function () {
    const logarithmic = this.logarithmic;

    if (logarithmic && this.options.custom.allowNegativeLog) {

        // Avoid errors on negative numbers on a log axis
        this.positiveValuesOnly = false;

        // Override the converter functions
        logarithmic.log2lin = num => {
            const isNegative = num < 0;

            let adjustedNum = Math.abs(num);

            if (adjustedNum < 10) {
                adjustedNum += (10 - adjustedNum) / 10;
            }

            const result = Math.log(adjustedNum) / Math.LN10;
            return isNegative ? -result : result;
        };

        logarithmic.lin2log = num => {
            const isNegative = num < 0;

            let result = Math.pow(10, Math.abs(num));
            if (result < 10) {
                result = (10 * (result - 1)) / (10 - 1);
            }
            return isNegative ? -result : result;
        };
    }
});

// Add support for negative axis values to the tick positioning function.
H.wrap(logAdditions, 'getLogTickPositions', function (
    proceed,
    interval,
    min,
    max,
    minor
) {
    if (
        !this.axis.options.custom.allowNegativeLog ||
        interval >= 0.5 ||
        interval < 0.08
    ) {
        return proceed.call(this, interval, min, max, minor);
    }

    const log = this,
        roundedMin = Math.floor(min),
        positions = [];
    let intermediate,
        i,
        j,
        len,
        pos,
        lastPos,
        break2;

    if (interval > 0.3) {
        intermediate = [1, 2, 4];
    } else if (interval > 0.15) {
        intermediate = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8];
    } else {
        intermediate = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    }

    for (i = roundedMin; i < max + 1 && !break2; i++) {
        len = intermediate.length;
        if (i <= 0) {
            for (j = len - 1; j >= 0 && !break2; j--) {
                pos = -log.log2lin(
                    (log.lin2log(-i) || 1) * intermediate[j]
                );

                if (
                    pos > min &&
                    (!minor || lastPos <= max) &&
                    typeof lastPos !== 'undefined'
                ) {
                    positions.push(lastPos);
                }
                if (lastPos > max) {
                    break2 = true;
                }
                lastPos = pos;
            }

            if (lastPos < min || lastPos > max) {
                lastPos = undefined;
            }
        }

        if (i === 0 && min <= 0 && max >= 0) {
            positions.push(0);
        }

        if (i >= 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < len && !break2; j++) {
                pos = log.log2lin((log.lin2log(i) || 1) * intermediate[j]);

                if (
                    pos > min &&
                    (!minor || lastPos <= max) &&
                    typeof lastPos !== 'undefined'
                ) {
                    positions.push(lastPos);
                }
                if (lastPos > max) {
                    break2 = true;
                }
                lastPos = pos;
            }
        }
    }

    return positions;
});

}`
and click on the "Toggle xAxis type" button underneath the graph, when we apply the logarithmic then the tickPositions disappear hence we don't apply the logarithmic scale for the xAxis but if you try it for the yAxis it will work. I would appreciate help on this... Thank you
I tried the provided logic from Highcharts which is included in the Fiddle but no success so far.

Hi, here is the example of improved extension: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v9wyxo2t/

Hello @magdalena Thank you for the improved extension. However it falls short when I have series data formatted in this way, Check the JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/kennylazer/0voLy4gr/2/ Thank you

This failed due to differences in the data set and how the axes ranges were calculated automatically. Since the negative logarithmic scale is a bit hacky, the ranges are not calculated correctly. Therefore, the axes min and max values should be specified manually https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m3Ljfz48/

Hello @magdalena if you still here, I found one minor issue in the solution you shared, you may check this loom for explanations https://www.loom.com/share/d86f858fd3b54ec4a3111a69e20a7506 and here is the JSFiddle codes where I replicated the issue https://jsfiddle.net/kennylazer/93g4bjd7/7/
Thank you

Highcharts sometimes rounds the min and max values when the startOnTick and endOnTick options are set to true. However, in this case, it also seems to be connected to the custom extension. The tick counter is a very complex algorithm, so I would not recommend modifying it. Instead, I suggest setting startOnTick and endOnTick to false. You can also experiment with the tickPositions option.
